# Full phpbb3 integration

Tags: php, phpbb3

How to integrate phpbb3 with site, not the login/registration form, i want to integrate the whole forum to the place of the template site.The forum to be in the site template.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically you need to install phpbb3 into the folder of your site in a forum folder, then install it. You then have a template folder with some file sinside called overall header and footer, if you modify those file you can make the forum smaller and fit inside your template.

Mine is integrated into my asp.net c# site and i jsut use isap to rewrite the php to follow the rest of the site and i also use a mod to rewrite the forum pages to be SEO firendly.

I also use my registration page on my site to register them into the database that the forum holds so you dont even need the registration page of phpbb. I also then have a scrip which logs you into the forums when you log into the site so it looks liek the forums are actually part of the site.

Let me know if you need a hand i know this back to front now :) thats phpbb2 to 3 and also the uphrade if needed i know all the little fixes you will need.